# How to wire up the arduino kit

Tags: arduino, sensor

I had the [SainSmart UNO+LCD Keypad+Prototype Shield+HC-SR04 Distance Sensor](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-uno-lcd-keypad-prototype-shield-hc-sr04-distance-sensor-kit-4-arduino.html). Didn't buy them combo.I am somewhat new working with the Arduino kits and was hoping you could show me a guide of how the boards are connected. I am using this kit for a school project and am having a bit of trouble.

Comment: Check this answer for UNO and LCD keypad. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/34222/8627 That should get you started.

Comment: The real question would be if any of the components want to use the same pins for different purposes.  I feel like there was recently a question about this very thing, where a particular problem of that nature was pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Arduino site and just use the examples.  If you use the normal shields and LCD then the Arduino Software already includes the drivers AND example code.  With only a few clicks you can have it working and then start customizing for your own project.

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystal?from=Tutorial.LCDLibrary

I have been using microprocessors for 30 years now and the hard part getting started with the Arduino is how EASY it is.

1 Download the software and unzip it.

2 Plug in your arduino to the USB and help Windows (if you use windows) to find the USB drivers.

3 Start the arduino software and select your Arduino model and COM port (the arduino driver installs as a serial port) from the Tools menu.

4 Use the File menu to open an example sketch (I suggest Blink and then LCD).

5 (this was hard part for me...) just the push the arrow button and it compiles and loads the program to the arduino board.  That's it!

Done.